# Problem Trailing Slash Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite, trailing-slash

When we generate SEO reports, the SEO crawler detects some pages as having the trailing slash and others not, but only on some of our pages.
All our pages have a trailing slash.
But we don't understand why 301 redirects are done on the one that doesn't.

https://example.com/hello/ 
https://example.com/hello

The difference is the trailing slash. He sort of thinks that there are 2 "different" pages - with exactly the same content - and then we are penalized.

This usually means that there is a link, or structured data information, somewhere with the address "example.com/hello", with a slash at the end. I have now looked at the html output of every page on one of our sites, and there is no mention of the address with the trailing slash anywhere ...

I'm starting to think maybe it's a problem with the .htaccess file? Or maybe somewhere else? ..

We are multisite so the .htaccess is tricky
Any suggestion would be welcome!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well in the crawl it detects all urls with end slash and without end smash,
But I don't understand why the urls without slash are in the crawl, while in the site map the urls are with trailing slashes and therefore good for indexing

Comment: I would therefore like to delete the urls without trailing slash from the crawl